# Conditionally change the root element in AngularJS directive's template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

I'm writing a directive which needs to have a different root element, based on a `mode` attribute I'm passing into directive. Below is an expected template file:

**Template file**:

```
<div ng-if="mode === 'full'">
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
    <input (a lot of attributes...)
           class="datepicker" />
</div>

<input ng-if="mode === 'short'"
       (a lot of attributes...)
       class="datepicker" />
```

But of course AngularJS complains that you must have a single root element in a template.

I know I could just split them into 2 files and load conditionally inside `templateUrl` (that is `templateUrl: function(tElem, tAttrs) { if tAttrs.mode === 'full' ...`).

But in my situation `<input class="datepicker" />` is an element with lots of different attributes, which are the same in both `full` and `short` modes. Ideally I'd put the `input` in a separate directive, but I feel it'd be an overkill in my case. Then keeping both outcomes in 2 different templates, would result in decoupling shared information (`input` attributes) into 2 separate files. Anyone changing anything on `input` in `short` mode would need to remember to make the same change on `input` in `full` mode, which would reside in different file.

**Question**:
How can I handle such situation inside a single template file?

**Notice**: I really can't add a single wrapping element (e.g. `<div>`) in this case. This would violate the layout I have.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just add a `<span>` above those two elements to serve as the root?

Comment: @DanielBeck: Yes there is. This is because of the layout problems it would introduce. The top elements have some particular classes with layout properties applied on them. It will stop working when we introduce wrapping `<span>` or `<div>` in the middle.

Comment: OK.  If this were my project, I'd find it much simpler to fix whatever in my CSS was causing an extra span to introduce layout problems, but if you prefer you can keep your two templates as strings and do the `$compile` dance once you know which one should be used.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Alright, but I expected some easier solution than this : ). Still thanks for the advice.